# in ms excel, is there a way to look up an array and edit data on the looked up row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, lookup

Just for a quick example, I have this table:

```
     A          B
1    student    grade
2    john       90
3    paul       93
4    peter      87
5    bill       84
6
7
```

Range or array is A2:B5.

- I want to type a name in A7 and B7 should display the corresponding grade.(i know it's VLOOKUP). Please read on for my real problem.
- I want to be able to change/modify the grade value in B7 such that, the change/modification will also reflect in the array(B4).
- Example: I put "peter" in A7, 87 will appear in B7. I change B7 from 87 to 95, the array (i.e. B4) should then show 95.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: You can do this with VBA.  It is a simple use of the `Worksheet_Change` event.  The only extra step is writing the old formula back in place once you have made the edit.  It's not hard, but doing this stuff in Excel is usually a sign that you chose the wrong tool to manage the data.  [Here is a very good reference on Worksheet_Change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you would like a `VLOOKUP` to suggest the student's most recent score, then override it with the actual score, and save the actual score to suggest for the next one?

Hence, my answer adds a lookup table to look up the most recent score (technically the 2nd-most recent occurrence of the student, because the moment you add `john` again, the most recent occurrence is blank until you override it). I suggest reading the following formulas in the order of C-D-G-H-B.

[image: before overriding]

C: Counts up the n-th instance of the student

D: Constructs a key for looking up

G: Summarizes the number of occurrences of the student

H: Looks up the 2nd-most recent score by concatenating the student with `occurrences - 1`

B: Brings the 2nd-most recent score over

Now the moment I type in the next student, it'll bring over the most recent score (again technically the 2nd-most recent occurrence), ready to override.